# Dolibarr DebugBar Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Psr\Log\AbstractLogger'

Tags: php

I'm testing Jenkins for autodeployment and after deplyment I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Psr\Log\AbstractLogger' not found in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/maximebf/debugbar/src/DebugBar/DataCollector/MessagesCollector.php:20 Stack trace: #0 /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/debugbar/class/autoloader.php(12): require_once() #1 [internal function]: {closure}('DebugBar\\DataCo...') #2 /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/debugbar/class/DataCollector/DolMessagesCollector.php(9): spl_autoload_call('DebugBar\\DataCo...') #3 /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/core/lib/functions.lib.php(1194): include_once('/share/ZFS2_DAT...') #4 /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/debugbar/class/DebugBar.php(8): dol_include_once('/debugbar/class...') #5 /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/main.inc.php(381): include_once('/share/ZFS2_DAT...') #6 /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/admin/modules.php(36): require('/share/ZFS2_DAT...') #7 {main} in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/maximebf/debugbar/src/DebugBar/DataCollector/MessagesCollector.php on line 20
```

I've checked with winmerge and all the files listed are identical in testing and production.

Both environments run on the same QNAP NAS, same Apache and same PHP, simply 2 different folders, no idea why one works but not the other.

As suggested here, https://github.com/Dolibarr/dolibarr/issues/15914, disabling DebugBar allows me to use Dolibarr again, but I have no idea why this error happens.

I've tried to install xdebug and see if I can step-by-step find the problem but QNAP sucks and I can't get xdebug to work.

Anyone has any idea how to pinpoint the problem?

Comment: Make sure the autoloader is required.

Comment: It is, as I said, files are identical in both folders yet one works and not the other. I just deleted the one that wasn't working and copied the working one and now it works.

Comment: And It keeps working after I run Jenkins deployment, something tells me I'll run into this problem again in the future.

Comment: Maybe your shared directory is the problem? `/share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/....` Ask your server admin.